# Stringize operator failure

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, stringification

The **C** and C++ standards all include text to the effect that if a stringize operation fails to produce a valid string literal token, the behavior is undefined. In C++11 this is actually possible, by including a newline character in a raw string literal. But the catch-all has always been there in the standards.

Is there any other way that stringize can produce UB, where UB or an ill-formed program hasn't already happened?

I'd be interested to hear about any dialect of **C** or C++ whatsoever. I'm [writing](http://code.google.com/p/c-plus) a preprocessor.

Comment: Most people struggle to get them to work, not to fail.

Comment: Hah… I'd like to verify that failure works, i.e. get a testcase. The trick with newlines doesn't help because I trap it and add a `\n`. (Well, it's a `"\\\\n"` if you're counting backslashes.)

Comment: Ok then I did not get what you are asking, you need preprocessor testcases. mcpp has some validation suite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stringify (`#`) operator only escapes `\` in string constants. Indeed, `\` has no particular significance outside of a string constant, except at the end of a line. It is, therefore, a preprocessing token (C section 6.4, C++ section 2.5).

Consequently, if we have

```
#define Q(X) #X
```

then

```
Q(\)
```

is a legitimate call: the `\` is a preprocessing token which is never converted to a token, so it's valid. But you can't stringify `\`; that would give you "\" which is not a valid string literal. Hence, the behaviour of the above is undefined.

Here's a more amusing test case:

```
#define Q(A) #A
#define ESCAPE(c) Q(\c)
const char* new_line=ESCAPE(n);
const char* undefined_behaviour=ESCAPE(x);
```

A less interesting case of an undefined stringify is where the stringified parameter would be too long to be a string literal. (The standards recommend that the maximum size of a string literal be at least 65536 characters, but say nothing about the maximum size of a macro argument, which could presumably be larger.)

Comment: Thanks! Shoulda thought of that. An unterminated string is already something I've tested in raw string catenation, and this gets trapped the exact same way :) . Your more amusing case doesn't appear to be UB in the preprocessor; it's exactly the same as writing `"\x"` or am I missing something? (Escape sequences are translated later.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: A string literal contains s-chars, escape-sequences and universal-character-names. `\x` is none of the above. So `"\x"` is not a valid string literal, the way I see it, and thus how the preprocessor deals with `ESCAPE(x)` (or, for that matter, `ESCAPE(*)`) is undefined. So the preprocessor could, if it chose, replace both of them with a smiley.

Comment: At least in C++, "Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 7 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics." So for a discrete preprocessor, I think trapping that would be a bit restrictive. But you are right, that is the grammar :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I agree, but I don't think that applies to `\x`. In any event, for UB there are no criteria at all, so whatever you decide is cool. You could even allow `ESCAPE(x) "7F"`, although `"\x" "7F"` is probably an error. (And even then, I don't think it's an error which needs to be reported.) By the way, how do you use stringify to generate a raw string literal, never mind put a newline into one?

Comment: Catenation can generate an unterminated raw string literal. A raw string literal containing a newline character is a valid input to stringizing. Those are different cases. But the same encapsulated tokenizer is used to implement both operators, so it's a common code path for me. As for that last example, `"\x" "7F"` is not allowed to catenate to `"\x7F"` because character translation and literal catenation occur in phases 5 and 6, respectively.